# Is there a word for saying something in a nice way without saying it?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

So, you are walking all day with a friend, you feel tired, you don't want to say: "I'm tired, let's stop", but say: "Oh dear, we've walked a lot today".

A friend promised to meet you to go for the football match at 9pm. It's 9 and you don't say: "You forgot the match right?", but for example: "Enjoy your dinner".

What's the word to describe these situations? Not sarcasm, because that is in a negative scope. Can we call it "rhetoric"?

Example, if the friend answers: "Oh thanks mate" and he really forgot, you would want to say: "'Enjoy your dinner' was ______".

Comment: Kindly refrain from abusing rhetoric in such a manner. It never did anything to you.

Comment: @TheNate that's why I asked the question in the first place

Comment: I *do* hope you knew I was joking. It's a perfectly good question, obviously.

Answer (score 3):

Euphemism - a mild or indirect word or expression substituted for one considered to be too harsh or blunt when referring to something unpleasant or embarrassing.

Answer (score 2):

Try *diplomatic*.

> **Diplomatic** *adjective*
>   1.1 Having or showing an ability to deal with people in a sensitive and tactful way
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/diplomatic)

Here are more words contributed by @TheNate (thanks!):

- thoughtful, kind - these relate more to the character of the *person*; and
- tactful, gracious - these relate more to the choice words and manner of communicating them.

Comment: Might want to toss in Tactful, thoughtful, gracious, and/or kind.

Comment: @TheNate Indeed :) . I particularly like *thoughtful* and *kind* as they speak to intent and character. *Diplomatic* as well as your contributions of *tactful* and *gracious* describe the *phrase* and *manner*.

Comment: Yeah, I tossed this here because you already had the best answer of those posted, imo. Figured expanding on that base would be  best for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

"[Imply](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/imply)" may foot the bill.

> Indicate the truth or existence of (something) by suggestion rather than explicit reference:
> *'salesmen who use jargon to imply superior knowledge'*

Instead of being negative it suggests inevitability.

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/imply